# Dependent probability of height and weight

Tags: probability

I am trying to find out the probability that someone is at least 6'4" (76 inches) and at least 210 lbs. According to the CDC the probability of each is:

$P(>76") = 99.18$ percentile. So $(1-0.9918) = 0.0082\%$

$P(>210) = 96.327$ percentile. So $(1-0.96327) = 0.03673\%$

I assume that these probabilities are dependent on each other. Is there anyway I can find out the probability of being both? Or is this impossible given these probabilities?

[CDC Weight per Age (2-20)](http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/data/zscore/wtage.csv)

[CDC Stature per Age (2-20)](http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/data/zscore/statage.csv)

[CDC Weight per Stature](http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/data/zscore/wtstat.csv)

Comment: "*the probability that someone is 6'4" (76 inches) and 210 lbs*".  You probably mean "the probability that someone is *at least* 6'4" (76 inches) and 210 lbs."

Comment: It seems that it cannot be done without information on how the two variables are related.

Comment: Does this improve the questions? @JoelReyesNoche

Comment: What do the variables L, M, S, P3, P5, P10, P25, P50, P75, P90, P95, and P97 represent?

Comment: I think this question is more appropriately asked at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You need to ballpark $p=P(W>210lb|H>76in)=P(W>95.3kg|H>193m)$. The frequency height drops off really fast at those heights and $W\approx H-100$, so $p\approx \frac 1 2$.

Answer (score 2):

If you can calculate the correlation and make assumptions about the normality of height and weight, then this seems to be a classic bivariate normal problem.
[Here's an example](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec21-25.pdf) I found online (Ex. 22.2, pg 7 of 15).

In other words, you need more information.

Comment: The tails (which are of interest here) are certainly not normal.

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information, you cannot find the probability of being both. If height and weight were *independent* of each other, then the probability of being both is easy to find: you just multiply the individual probabilities. However, there are uncountably many ways in which the two variables could depend on each other if you assume they are not independent. Thus it seems as if you need some more information to answer your question.